# Redirecting Urls with Query String to pretty Url in NGINX

Tags: php, apache, nginx, mod-rewrite, seo

I am using nginx as reverse proxy with apache for my website. I have pretty url's enabled for SEO purpose, with NGINX rewrite URL's.

for example the pretty url :

```
mysite.com/song/I-love-music
```

works for this ugly url :

```
mysite.com/song.php?url=I-love-music
```

And it works perfectly.

But I have an issue now, if someone visits this type of urls directly

```
mysite.com/song.php?url=I-love-music
```

Then this url is loading properly , same as

```
mysite.com/song.php?url=I-love-music
```

It is a big problem for SEO purpose, I need this ugly url to permanently redirected to this pretty url :

```
mysite.com/song/I-love-music
```

Please help me how do I rewrite urls in NGINX for this. I tried with apache rewrite rules in htaccess but that gives me server error..

Comment: any suggestions, anyone?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, Please help me. I have tried all the other solutions.

Comment: Not a fix, but I suggest you look at a front controller, especially with Nginx. You send everything that’s not a file or directory to your /index.php file, and use this file to handle all of your url routing. Look at php’s $_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI’] variable, and handle the logic using this variable.